# Is it correct to say that matrix norm that are unitarily invariant norm has this property $|||U||| = |||I|||$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it correct to say that matrix norm that are unitarily invariant norm has this property $|||U||| = |||I_n|||$, where $U \in M_n$ is some unitary/permutation matrix, and $I_n$ is an identity matrix?

The definition of unitarily invariant norm is: $|||UAV|||=|||A|||$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices.

Thank you

p.s.: I get that $|||I|||$ is not necessarily equal to $1$ (unless it's an induced norm).

Comment: What do you mean by "unitarily invariant"? The answer depends entirely on that.

Comment: The definition of unitarily invariant norm is: $|||UAV|||=|||A|||$, where $U$ and $V$ are unitary matrices.

Comment: $U=UII$, so ...

Comment: $|||UI||| = |||I|||$ should be same, right? I understand it is obvious and trivial, but just wanted to make sure.

Comment: You need to be more confident in yourself.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I am trying my best and working on that (perhaps, maths makes me bit edgy but still I don't want to give up and hesitate asking stupid questions). Apologies for asking stupid questions.

Comment: That's not the point, asking "stupid" question. I have met several successful mathematicians who are not afraid of asking even if the question may be perceived as "stupid", they don't care. :-)

Comment: I gathered that the point is that I need to be more confident in myself :). I think I have not been practicing mathematics that much. That's why I have joined this group such that I can learn from you experts who are so kind and helpful, and it pushes me to practice more often.